# After using .destroy() method on Scrolled text widget in Tkinter the Scrollbar doesn't disappear

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm using the Scrolled Text widget in Tkinter, but when I call the destroy() method on it the Box disappears but the scroll bar stays. I provided some images so you can get a better understanding of what I'm talking about. 
How can I fix this?
[image: Picture 1, Item Description][image: Picture 2, after calling the destroy() method]

Here is the code, I'm talking about the item_description widget.

```
def add_item():

  global options
  global add
  global remove
  global display

  add.config(state = "disabled", relief = "sunken")
  remove.config(state = "disabled")
  display.config(state = "disabled")

  name_label = Label(options, text = "Item Name")
  name_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_name = Entry(options, width = 35)
  item_name.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")

  description_label = Label(options, text = "Item Description")
  description_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_description = ScrolledText(options, width = 25, height = 5)
  item_description.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")

  price_label = Label(options, text = "Item Price")
  price_label.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_price = Entry(options, width = 5)
  item_price.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_price.insert(0, "$0.00")

  stock_label = Label(options, text = "Stock")
  stock_label.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_stock = Entry(options, width = 5)
  item_stock.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

  calories_label = Label(options, text = "Calories")
  calories_label.grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_calories = Entry(options, width = 5)
  item_calories.grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

  date_label = Label(options, text = "Expiry Date")
  date_label.grid(row = 11, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_expiry_date = Entry(options, width = 12)
  item_expiry_date.grid(row = 12, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_expiry_date.insert(0, "dd/mm/yyyy")

  stock_add = Button(options, text = "Add", borderwidth = 2, relief = "groove",
    command = lambda: add_to_stock(item_name.get(),
      item_description.get("1.0", "end-1c"),
        item_price.get(),
          item_stock.get(),
            item_calories.get(),
              item_expiry_date.get()))

  stock_add.grid(row = 13, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

  global widgets_add
  widgets_add = [name_label, item_name, description_label, item_description, price_label, item_price,
    stock_label, item_stock, calories_label, item_calories, date_label, item_expiry_date, stock_add]
```

Here is the code where I remove all the widgets from the widgets_add list, which is made at the end of the previous code.

```
def remove_add():
  # Remove item adding dialog

  global widgets_add
  for widget in widgets_add:
    widget.destroy()
```

Comment: `tkinter` module doesn't destroy the scroll bar when it destroys the text zone. You can redraw the entire window if you want to destroy the scroll bar. I will try to find an other solution.

Comment: ScrolledText creates a Frame internally to hold the Text and Scrollbar widgets.  So destroy() only destroys the Text widget.  You need to use `item_description.frame.destroy()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `ScrolledText` widget actually creates

```
Frame
    Scrollbar
    ScrolledText
```

but only returns a reference to `ScrolledText`. When you `destroy()` that, the `Frame` and `Scrollbar` get left behind.

The easiest solution would be to add all of your controls to a `Frame` instance and `destroy()` that instead. In this way you don't have to keep track of them in a separate list.

So, assuming `options` is your `Tk` instance:

```py
def add_item():

  global options
  global add
  global remove
  global display

  add.config(state = "disabled", relief = "sunken")
  remove.config(state = "disabled")
  display.config(state = "disabled")

  options_frame = Frame(options)

  name_label = Label(options_canvas, text = "Item Name")
  name_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_name = Entry(options_canvas, width = 35)
  item_name.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")

  description_label = Label(options_canvas, text = "Item Description")
  description_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_description = ScrolledText(options_canvas, width = 25, height = 5)
  item_description.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")

  price_label = Label(options_canvas, text = "Item Price")
  price_label.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_price = Entry(options_canvas, width = 5)
  item_price.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_price.insert(0, "$0.00")

  stock_label = Label(options_canvas, text = "Stock")
  stock_label.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
  item_stock = Entry(options_canvas, width = 5)
  item_stock.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

  calories_label = Label(options_canvas, text = "Calories")
  calories_label.grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_calories = Entry(options_canvas, width = 5)
  item_calories.grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

  date_label = Label(options_canvas, text = "Expiry Date")
  date_label.grid(row = 11, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_expiry_date = Entry(options_canvas, width = 12)
  item_expiry_date.grid(row = 12, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)
  item_expiry_date.insert(0, "dd/mm/yyyy")

  stock_add = Button(options_canvas, text = "Add", borderwidth = 2, relief = "groove",
    command = lambda: add_to_stock(item_name.get(),
      item_description.get("1.0", "end-1c"),
        item_price.get(),
          item_stock.get(),
            item_calories.get(),
              item_expiry_date.get()))

  stock_add.grid(row = 13, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

def remove_add():
  # Remove item adding dialog

  global options_frame
  options_frame.destroy()
```

Comment: Why don't use Frame instead of Canvas?  Also, a ScrolledText consists of Frame, Text (not ScrolledText) and Scrollbar widgets.

Comment: You're right, Frame makes more sense.

I'm not sure about the Text vs. ScrolledText issue though, I actually see this: https://i.imgur.com/AOXLn0I.png